# What is the origin of "take one's medicine"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, phrase-origin, origin-unknown

I would really like to know where the idiom "take one's medicine" comes from. At first l thought it was another version of *taste of their own medicine*, but I found that these two have completely different meaning, I Googled it but I couldn't find its origin.

Comment: If you mean _To endure an unpleasant obligation, especially a punishment_, surely it's obvious? Medicine often tastes unpleasant, or did when it was commonly taken in liquid form, but we know we have to take it in order to get better.

Comment: I found this info: The figurative phrase take (one's) medicineL "submit to something disagreeable" is recorded by 1865; that of dose of (one's) own medicine is by 1894

Comment: Please specify the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The earliest recorded use of the phrase “to take one’s medicine” in an English publication was in 1865. The phrase appeared in a book titled The Life of Abraham Lincoln by Ward Hill Lamon

The book quoted a letter from Lincoln to his friend Joshua Speed, in which he wrote:
I have endured a great deal of ridicule without much malice; and have received a great deal of kindness, not quite free from ridicule. I am used to it. I can, therefore, bear it. I have known what it was to be generous and to be mean; to be wise and to be foolish; to be radical and to be conservative; and I have resolved to take my medicine as the doctor prescribes.

Comment: But that usage by him is the medical usage of it. So, it doesn't count.

Comment: The subject of that section of Lincoln’s letter is on bearing the ridicule he has received and compares it to taking his medicine.  If he was being literal, the doctor was probably a liquor store.

Comment: Yes: the figurative phrase take (one's) medicine "submit to something disagreeable" is recorded by 1865; that of dose of (one's) own medicine is by 1894.

Answer (score 1):

In the sense of “to accept a (deserved) punishment or reprimand” according to [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/ruxzomi#aoe4pma) the expression was first used in the second half of the 19th century:

> 1865  [SA]    A.D. Richardson Secret Service 75: *The leaders refused to take their own medicine .*

Medicine in the figurative sense dates a bit earlier:

> Medicine: punishment, usually deserved.
>
> 1830  [US]    Owl (NY) 11 Sept. n.p.: *E.K. has promised to administer to W.C. [...] ‘a dose of medicine that would purge his malignant disposition’.*

Comment: The idiom in question hinges on the decision to take the vile stuff of one's own accord. Better that than the probable alternative. It isn't punitive per say, it's choosing the lesser evil.